# Create a Cancel button for Joomla 3.2 custom component

Tags: joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I am trying to build a Joomla 3.2 custom component and am having a difficult time getting the cancel button (admin section) to work. I've added the button, but when I click it I get the error:

> 0 Invalid controller: name='helloworld', format=''

This is for the component 'helloworld' and the view 'goodbye'. Could someone look at my files and tell me how to get the 'cancel' button to work? I just want it to close the current page and return to the default component page.

Thanks for any help.

**/administrator/views/goodbye/view.html.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla view library
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

/**
 * HTML View class for the HelloWorld Component
 */
class HelloWorldViewGoodbye extends JViewLegacy
{
    // Overwriting JView display method
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->addToolbar();
        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }

        protected function addToolbar()
    {
            JToolbarHelper::title('Race Results','tbar');
            JToolbarHelper::cancel('helloworld.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
        }
}
```

**/administrator/views/goodbye/tmpl/default.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>
<h1>Cancel Race Results</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
        if (task == 'helloworld.cancel')
        {
            Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('helloworld-form'));
        }
    }
</script>

<form id="helloworld-form" name="adminForm" method="post" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=goodbye'); ?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_helloworld" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="goodbye" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>

</form>
```

**/administrator/controllers/goodbye.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla modelitem library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

/**
 * HelloWorld Model
 */
class HelloWorldControllerGoodbye extends JControllerLegacy
{

    public function edit() {

    }

    public function add() {

    }

    public function remove() {

    }

    public function save() {

    }

    public function apply() {

    }

}
```

**/administrator/models/goodbye.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla modelitem library
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

/**
 * HelloWorld Model
 */
class HelloWorldModelGoodbye extends JModelLegacy
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change HelloWorldViewGoodbye to GoodbyeViewGoodbye and same other.

Answer (score 3):

depending on action you would like to achieve
Add to controller

```
    public function cancel($key = null) {
    JSession::checkToken() or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option='.$this->option.'&view=name_of the_view' , false));
    return true;
}
```

In view.html add condition to your button

```
    if (condition when to use button)
        {
        JToolbarHelper::cancel('your_controller_name.cancel');
        }
    else
        {
        JToolbarHelper::cancel('your_controller_name', 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
        }
```